# ng-if not working with ng-repeat and radio button

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have the following html template:

```
    <div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="cont">
        <table>
        <tr><th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</th></tr>
        
        <tr ng-repeat="(i, row) in people">
          <td ng-repeat="(j, column) in columns">
            <input type="radio" name="select" ng-if="column === 'id'">
            <span>{{row[column]}}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>                        
    </div>    
</div>
```

Then I define my Ctrl as follow

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.selectedId = 'aaaaa';
    
    $scope.columns = ['id','name', 'age'];
    
    $scope.people=[
        { 
            'id':'aaaaa', 'name':'rachit', 'age':11
        },
        { 
            'id':'bbbbb', 'name':'gulati', 'age':12
        },
        { 
            'id':'ccccc', 'name':'rocks', 'age': 13
        }
    ]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/en91zuxb/

it's showing radio input for all the item, while my intention is to only show the radio button on the first column, because the 1st column is the `id` column... ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your angular version is old, this was an error related to angularjs < 1.2. Try upgrading your angularjs version or use ng-show instead.

Following code worked for me.

```
<input type="radio" name="select" ng-show="column == 'id' ">
```